# How to define the property file in node js?

Tags: node.js, properties

I have found an article about properties file reader in node js here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/properties-reader

There is a module as 'properties-reader'. But, I'm unable to understand how to define the property file. Should it be a json?

Comment: have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/java-properties. seems to be better.

Answer (score 8):

It's an ini format, as described [here](https://github.com/steveukx/properties):

```
# contents of properties file
[main]
some.thing = foo

[blah]
some.thing = bar
```

Answer (score 7):

Its not a Json format, but in ini format.

Steps to set up properties file and to read it from your node module:

1. make any properties file such as app.properties inside your project directory. The file may contain data like:

   ```
   \#comment(ignored)

   sever.port=3000
   ```
2. Run the following command to install properties-reader locally:

   ```
   npm i properties-reader
   ```
3. once done use the properties-reader like this:

   ```
   const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
   const prop = PropertiesReader('path/to/app.properties');

   /*gets property from path/to/app.properties
   You can also export this function using module.exports*/
   getProperty = (pty) => {return prop.get(pty);}

   //call the getProperty method
   console.log(getProperty('server.port')); //3000
   ```

Easy as that!

Comment: My property file has comments that start with #, I get Syntax Error 

# ApplicationResources
^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1018:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1066:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92

Comment: @Anuja Kindly follow the link below for your concern. I did retry properties file with comments and it works perfectly fine for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59073774/node-js-syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token