# node.js SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error

I have downloaded and installed node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/.
I want to run a js file:

```
console.log('hello');
```

I run ***node app.js***

And get a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11[39m
```

My OS Info:

```
Version: 10.0.18362
BuildNumber: 18362
OSArchitecture: 32-bit
```

node.js v12.13.1

Comment: Provide your OS info/ nodejs info. Show data returned from `node -v`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you copy some unicode characters from word or something?

try retyping the `console.log('hello')` Something like this has happened to me before, when I copied some code from a word document.

Comment: Oh, yea. I created the file by redirecting output from echo command in powershell. Thank you, sir.

Comment: Just happened to me because a code sample I copied from SO contained hidden Unicode line separators `"\u2028"`. It became apparent in a hex editor: `E2 80 8B` (`â€‹`).

Answer (score 11):

The problem was that I created the file by redirecting output from echo command in powershell. It had UTF-16 LE encoding, should be UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue for hours, `echo const http=require('http')` >> `index.js`. Solved

Answer (score 0):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq010.png)

if you take a loot at the picture. you can see th error is on R21.
You are trying to close the if from r14 with a ) instead of a }

Comment: write code instead of  providing it in an image