# Executing Stored Procedure in JavaScript to insert into Snowflake error

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wrote a JavaScript program to just query table in Snowflake. I saved the file with .js extension.

While executing .js file through git Bash(**node filename.js**) I am getting following error:

```
Syntax Error: Invalid or unexpected token
?[90m    at wrap Safe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)?[39m
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:1
0)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_ma
in.js:74:12)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47?[39m
```

Could anyone please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you have a Syntax error provide the code snippet where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js

This error appears to be at a very early point of execution, where the program input (`filename.js` contents) gets loaded and interpreted. This error is unrelated to the use of Snowflake's connector library.

The `Invalid or unexpected token` indicates that it found an unacceptable keyword or character that's considered illegal in JavaScript syntax.

This is just a further guess on the above, but if you've used a non-standard code editor, such as `TextEdit.app`, `Notepad`, `Microsoft Word`, etc. to write your code, then there's a good chance they injected smart quotes (`“`), or smart dashes (`–`) in place of plain ASCII quotes (`"`) or dashes (`-`). Also see this past question for further ideas on what the bad characters (or encoding) could be: [node.js SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59073774/node-js-syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token)

It'd also be of help if you can upload a small code sample that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. I will try this and update you. I will try to upload my code also.